# Why does a cert I made with New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My get stored in Cert:\CurrentUser\CA

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate

I made a self signed certificate like so on Windows 10:

```perl
$MasterKeyDNSName = 'CN=Always Encrypted Sample'
Write-Host "Creating Self Signed Certificate $($MasterKeyDNSName)"
$Cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate `
    -Subject $MasterKeyDNSName `
    -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My ` 
    -KeyExportPolicy Exportable `
    -Type DocumentEncryptionCert `
    -KeyUsage DataEncipherment `
    -KeySpec KeyExchange
$CmkPath = "Cert:\CurrentUser\My\$($cert.ThumbPrint)"
Write-Verbose "Column Master Key Certificate Path: $($CmkPath)"
```

The cert had a thumbprint of `B91A912CF632575F784CDE485DA37AB2F23DB6BA` and appeared in e registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\CA\Certificates\B91A912CF632575F784CDE485DA37AB2F23DB6BA`.

From powershell I could access it with via both `Cert:\CurrentUser\My\B91A912CF632575F784CDE485DA37AB2F23DB6BA` and `Cert:\CurrentUser\CA\B91A912CF632575F784CDE485DA37AB2F23DB6BA`.

According to the [Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccrypto/system-store-locations#cert_system_store_current_user), the My folder uses the .Default store and the CA folder uses the .Default, GroupPolicy and .LocalMachine physical stores.

Is My like a symlink and CA is the authoritative location?

Answer (score 2):

The My and CA stores are indeed different.

If you opened MMC certmgr, you would see that My is Personal and CA is Intermediate Certification Authorities.

This command:

```
$Cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject 'CN=Always Encrypted Sample'
```

will generate certificate in 3 stores (unless your current path is Cert:\CurrentUser or Cert:\CurrentUser\My ):

- cert:\LocalMachine\my
- cert:\LocalMachine\ca
- cert:\CurrentUser\ca

The only reason of such **undocumented** behavior I could see is a clumsy attempt to make the self-signed certificate valid immediately when generated.

If instead of `ca`, the generated certificate was automatically posted into `root` store (which is Trusted Root Certificate Authorities), that goal would be accomplished.

Maybe a developer, creating the `New-SelfSignedCertificate` code, was confused by the story name `ca`, because everywhere CA is *Certificate Authority*, and only there it is *Intermediate Certificate Authority*

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but then why don't I see a registry entry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates\B91A912CF632575F784CDE485DA37AB2F23DB6BA`?